# Trying to copy google-services.json to root of Phonegap build project

Tags: cordova, plugins, firebase, build

Trying to copy google-services.json to root of Phonegap build project from firebase plugin.

https://github.com/jvwelzen/cordova-plugin-firebase

for iOs copying GoogleService-Info.plist to root is working fine but for android is seems not to work, any idea's are welcom.

plugin.xml

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-firebase" version="0.1.18"
xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <name>Google Firebase Plugin</name>

 <license>MIT</license>

 <engines>
  <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.2.0" />
 </engines>

 <platform name="android">
  <js-module name="FirebasePlugin" src="www/firebase.js">
   <clobbers target="FirebasePlugin" />
  </js-module>
  <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
   <feature name="FirebasePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
   </feature>
  </config-file>
  <config-file parent="/resources" target="res/values/strings.xml">
   <string name="google_app_id">@string/google_app_id</string>
  </config-file>
  <config-file parent="/resources" target="res/values/strings.xml">
   <string name="google_api_key">@string/google_api_key</string>
  </config-file>
  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  </config-file>
  <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
   <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
   </service>
   <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
   </service>
   <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver"></receiver>

  <source-file src="src/android/google-services.json" target-dir="." />
  <source-file src="src/android/FirebasePlugin.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/firebase" />
  <source-file src="src/android/OnNotificationOpenReceiver.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/firebase" />
  <source-file src="src/android/FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/firebase" />
  <source-file src="src/android/FirebasePluginMessagingService.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/firebase" />

  <framework src="src/android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
  <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+" />
  <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+" />
  <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+" />
  <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+" />
 </platform>

 <platform name="ios">
  <js-module name="FirebasePlugin" src="www/firebase.js">
   <clobbers target="FirebasePlugin" />
  </js-module>
  <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
   <feature name="FirebasePlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FirebasePlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
   </feature>
  </config-file>
  <config-file parent="aps-environment" target="*/Entitlements-Debug.plist">
      <string>development</string>
  </config-file>
  <config-file parent="aps-environment" target="*/Entitlements-Release.plist">
   <string>production</string>
  </config-file>

  <resource-file src="src/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist" target="Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  
  <header-file src="src/ios/AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.h" />
  <source-file src="src/ios/AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m" />
  <header-file src="src/ios/FirebasePlugin.h" />
  <source-file src="src/ios/FirebasePlugin.m" />

  <header-file src="src/ios/Firebase/Firebase.h" />

  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseCore.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/FirebaseInstanceID.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleUtilities.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Messaging/FirebaseMessaging.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Messaging/GoogleIPhoneUtilities.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/Crash/FirebaseCrash.framework" />
  <framework custom="true" src="src/ios/Firebase/RemoteConfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework" />
 </platform>

 <platform name="browser">
  <js-module name="FirebasePlugin" src="www/firebase-browser.js">
   <clobbers target="FirebasePlugin" />
  </js-module>
 </platform>

 <hook src="scripts/after_prepare.js" type="after_prepare" />
</plugin>
```

after_prepare.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

var getValue = function(config, name) {
    var value = config.match(new RegExp('<' + name + '>(.*?)</' + name + '>', "i"))
    if(value && value[1]) {
        return value[1]
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

function fileExists(path) {
  try  {
    return fs.statSync(path).isFile();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function directoryExists(path) {
  try  {
    return fs.statSync(path).isDirectory();
  }
  catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

var config = fs.readFileSync("config.xml").toString()
var name = getValue(config, "name")

if (directoryExists("platforms/ios")) {
  var paths = ["GoogleService-Info.plist", "platforms/ios/www/GoogleService-Info.plist"];

  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    if (fileExists(paths[i])) {
      try {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(paths[i]).toString();
        fs.writeFileSync("platforms/ios/" + name + "/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist", contents)
      } catch(err) {
        process.stdout.write(err);
      }

      break;
    }
  }
}

if (directoryExists("platforms/android")) {
  var paths = ["google-services.json", "platforms/android/assets/www/google-services.json"];

  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    if (fileExists(paths[i])) {
      try {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(paths[i]).toString();
        fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/google-services.json", contents);

        var json = JSON.parse(contents);
        var strings = fs.readFileSync("platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml").toString();

        // strip non-default value
        strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_app_id">([^\@<]+?)</string>', "i"), '')

        // strip non-default value
        strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_api_key">([^\@<]+?)</string>', "i"), '')

        // strip empty lines
        strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('(\r\n|\n|\r)[ \t]*(\r\n|\n|\r)', "gm"), '$1')

        // replace the default value
        strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_app_id">([^<]+?)</string>', "i"), '<string name="google_app_id">' + json.client[0].client_info.mobilesdk_app_id + '</string>')

        // replace the default value
        strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_api_key">([^<]+?)</string>', "i"), '<string name="google_api_key">' + json.client[0].api_key[0].current_key + '</string>')

        fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml", strings);
      } catch(err) {
        process.stdout.write(err);
      }

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to copy google-services.json from cordova-plugin-firebase. Instead create a new one at [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)!.
Create a new project and add ios/android. Just follow the steps and you should get the required files.